# Cannot start geth miner by admin.miner.start()

Tags: go-ethereum

Start the geth console by `geth --maxpeers=50 console`

then using `admin.miner.start()` to start mining, but got the error below

```
TypeError: Cannot access member 'start' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is there any where I can check for, or any online reference, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `miner.start()` to start mining. Reference can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining).